# What is the expected value?

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value

I have this statement:

> In a bag there are four cards marked with the letter $A$ and six cards
>   marked with the letter $B$, all of equal shape and size. A game consists
>   of taking out two random cards, one by one and with replacement, where
>   if both correspond to type $A$, then you win $\$1,000$; if both cards are
>   different, you earn $\$200$; and if both cards have the letter $B$, then 
>   $\$1,500$ is lost. If you want to participate in the game, then it is
>   estimated, from the calculation of the expected value, that the result of the game
>   will be:
>
> A) Lose $\$256$
>
> B) Lose  $\$284$
>
> C) Win $\$100$
>
> D) Win  $\$256$
>
> E) Neither win nor lose

My development was:

First i need to get the probability of get $AA$ or $AB$ or $BA$ or $BB$

The cases for $AA$ is equal to $\binom{4}{2}_{rep} = 10$

The cases for  $AB$ is equal to $\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{6}{1}=24$

The cases for $BA$ is equal to $\binom{6}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{1}=24$

The cases for $BB$ is equal to $\binom{6}{2}_{rep} = 21$

The total cases of choose two cards of a total of $10$ is equal to $10 + 24 + 24 + 21 = 79$

Thus, $1000(\frac{10}{79}) + 200(\frac{48}{79}) - 1500(\frac{21}{79}) = E(X)$

$E(X) = \approx-149$ or *Lose $\$149$*, but this result don't appear in the answers. So, what ins wrong with my development? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Selection with replacement means that after each draw the result is
>   recorded, but the **card itself is replaced before the next draw**.

So the number of ways to draw $AA$ is $4 \times 4 = 16$ and not $10$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A strong suggestion that your numbers aren't right: you say there are $79$ possible ways you could experience this game. That's a very prime number in a context where I would expect a highly composite number.

I advise instead discarding this case-counting thing and just working with probabilities directly (since you're drawing cards with replacement). The probability of $A$ is $\frac{2}{5}$, so the probability of $AA$ is $\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^2$.

Comment: I want to know where are my mistake and why,  also with some solution that is similar to my solution